# graceful shutdown of primary thread in case of secondary thread died

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am working on a project where lots of independent components work together to perform the task and every component has separate heartbeat thread. This heartbeat thread is foreground thread.

I want to enable graceful shutdown of component in case heartbeat thread died.

adding more information...

for example....we have a component called Request Monitor (server component) which talks the database and retrieve the data on request basis and return the data to client application. This all tasks are performed by primary thread.

I also want my client application to check the health of server components so I created another thread which sends a heartbeat message to client applications whoever is registed with server components. That message contain nothing but server information like machine name, process id etc. we consider this as heartbeat information means server is alive and responding to incoming requests. Server components sends this information after every 10 mins.

Since this heartbeat information is foreground thread, whole application shutdown if this secondary thread died.

I want to perform some tasks in case the heartbeat thread died like cleanup some resources, completeng already received requests etc.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more context and information.  Your question is too vague, and includes no specifics.  Show code if possible.

Comment: *...separate heartbeat thread. This heartbeat thread is foreground thread...*. What do you mean by foreground thread? UI thread? Non Daemon thread? How are you testing for thread's death? What would qualify as a *graceful* shutdown? Who/what component is responsible for this housekeeping? Maybe some code please.

Comment: ..or if a large, distrubuted system, some kind of overview.  I'm as baffled by your question as @MystereMan

Comment: //preparing Heartbeat Message
                        HeartbeatThreadInformation heartbeatThreadInformation =
                            new HeartbeatThreadInformation
                                {
                                    IsProcessing = serviceThread.IsProcessing,
                                    ThreadId = serviceThread.ThreadId,
                                    LogFileLocation = logLocation
                                };

Comment: Thread heartbeatThread = new Thread(_sender.Start);
                heartbeatThread.Start();

Start()
{
HeartbeatThreadInformation heartbeatThreadInformation =
                            new HeartbeatThreadInformation
                                {
                                    IsProcessing = serviceThread.IsProcessing,
                                    ThreadId = serviceThread.ThreadId,
                                    LogFileLocation = logLocation
                                };
_heartbeatTopic.SendMessage(message);

                    Thread.Sleep(_heartbeatInterval);
}

Comment: Hmmm, what resources need actually cleaning up? You've tagged the question with C# and .NET, and as I understand it all object destructors/finalisers will get called on quit anyway. So (for example) an object representing a database connection should do what ever is necessary to cleanly close that connection on exit automatically, shouldn't it? Including unmanaged resources?